# Nginx strange upstream address after app restart

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, docker

I have an application running in a container with an exposed port 8082. There is also an nginx configuration, part of which is shown below. In a normal situation, I see `upstream: 127.0.0.1:8082` in the access log, which is correct. But when I stop the application container and start it again, I see `to: localhost` in the logs for about 5-6 seconds, which leads to a 502 error on the site. At this time, the application is already live and running on port 8082. Why does this happen?

```
server {
    server_name acme.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/acme.log upstreamlog;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;
       proxy_next_upstream error timeout http_502;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
       proxy_set_header Upgrade websocket;
       proxy_set_header Connection Upgrade;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ... some other Certbot lines ...
}
```

```
> sudo nginx -T | grep acme.com
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
    server_name acme.com;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, `localhost` means both the IPv4 `127.0.0.1` and the IPv6 `::1`.
When NGINX forwards traffic to the upstream, it takes the host name you gave which yields both IPv4 and IPv6, while I'm guessing your upstream is IPv4 only.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I managed to solve the problem by replacing `proxy_pass http://localhost:8082;` with `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;`.